Transform this graphQL to a JSON object
I have this graphQL and I need to transform it to JSON object:
mutation createTest {
  createTest (input: { note:"test", assets: [Asset._idA, Asset._idB, ...],expiration:"2025-07-02T00:19:19Z"}){
    id  
  }
}

and the variable is just the id as
{
  "id": "XXX"
}

where xxx is a given ID.
I have tried with this way but it does not work:
{
  "query": "mutation createTest { createTest (input: { note:\"test\", assets: [Asset._idA, Asset._idB, ...],expiration:\"2025-07-02T00:19:19Z\"}){ id }}",
  "variables": {
    "id": "XXX"
  }
}

Can you help on this? Thanks!

There is no variable in your query. Why are you trying to pass one?

I never heard of graphql until a few days ago. ok, without variables it still does not work. it was tried as:
{
"query": "mutation createTest { createTest (input: { note:"test node", assets: [Asset._idA, Asset._idB, ...],expiration:"2025-07-02T00:19:19Z"}){ id }}"
}
Can you help? Thanks!

We can't help if you don't tell us what the problem is or what error you are getting. Maybe you'll also need to share the relevant part of the schema, or at least tell us which public api you're using.

ok. the error goes as : ""Invalid syntax with ANTLR error 'token recognition error at: '._'' at line 1 column 78"  -- it refers somewhere near asset...

Yes, [Asset._idA, Asset._idB, ...] is not valid GraphQL. What did you mean by that? What values do you want to send? Did you read https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#arguments?

I have substituted  it by [Asset.xxxx]  where xxxx is the real id (numbers mainly). But it does not work.
{ "query": "mutation createTest { createTest (input: { note:"test node", assets: [Asset.xxxxx],expiration:"2025-07-02T00:19:19Z"}){ id }}" }

Nevermind. it was this way:
{
"query": "mutation createTest { createShare (input: { assets: "xxxxxxxxxx",expiration:"2027-07-09T00:19:18Z"}){ id }}"
}
thanks for your input bergi!
